# HttpPost addHeader does not work - headers are untouched

Tags: c#, java, android, http-headers

I can't get the `addHeaders` method to work when using HttpPost in Java/Android. This is what I doing in the Android app:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonString, HTTP.UTF_8);
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse resp = client.execute(httpPost);
```

and this is what I see on the server-side (in Wireshark):

[image]

As you can see, there is no sign of any "Accept-Encoding". If I break in the C#-server and look at the WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest, then it's also missing there:

[image]

It doesn't matter what headers I add, they simply don't show up.

Comment: Have you tried first setting the entity and then adding the header?

Comment: Try setting another meaningless (`X-`) header and see if that gets sent.

Comment: I am setting another header ("TESTTEST") but that doesnt get passed either...

Comment: And suddenly, without any change, it just started working. Very strange... Now I have another problem, but Ill post on that separately.

Comment: seeing the same here in ordinary Java. Replacing with `setHeader()` fixes it, but I'd like an explanation.